# Metamask: Is aprove equivalent to 100% automatic transactions?

Tags: metamask, erc-20-approve

When we do an approve in metamask we see this text:

> Is this site trustworthy? By granting this permission, you authorize
> [Site] to retire your [Token] and **automate** transactions for you.

What does that **automate** mean?

Does it mean that that [Site] can remove all my [Token] from my wallet without me approving the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you approve an address to certain token amount it will be able to withdraw up to the approved amount.

Some contracts use the maximum number representable, `typeinfo(uint).max`, as a wildcard that means all available available balance.

Comment: But once approved, as the alert says, can they make automatic transactions without me having to confirm the transactions in Metamask?

Comment: @user2983041 Once a contract is approved, it can call `transferFrom` at anytime, by anyone. It is important to approve only the contract you trust.

Comment: But then why after approving, and sending a transaction in Uniswap, do we have to confirm that transaction in Metamask? Could a malicious swap do such transactions without having to confirm once approved?

Comment: @user2983041 It is because Uniswap was programmed that way, it only withdraws from msg.sender and the amount specified by the user. A malicious contract could withdraw from any account it was approved up to the amount approved.